# Javascript unwrap part of element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could one go about unwrapping an element, without removing the parent element?

For example, if I had the following

```
<strong>Some text <span>and some more text.</span> And a little more.</strong>
```

Is there a javascript or jquery way to unwrap the span, resulting in

```
<strong>Some text </strong><span>and some more text</span><strong>And a little more.</strong>
```

I can use jquery's unwrap to simply remove the strong tag from the span, but that results in the text outside of the span also losing the tag.

Comment: Is it always this pair: `strong` and `span`?

Comment: Idk about unwrapping, but couldn't you just remove the span as a child of the strong element and then append it to the parent element of the strong tag?

Comment: @PM 77-1, No, its a mix of strong, em, u, strike, span, ul and ol.

Really, being able to unwrap ol and ul would suit my purposes, but I wanted to be more general in my purpose. Basically I need to unwrap lists from having any parent elements (other than div/body)

Comment: @taylorc93, thats a good idea actually. I'm not quite sure how to append elements as I havn't used jquery all that much. Could you write me an answer with that solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
$("strong").contents().filter(function () {
    return (this.nodeType==3)
}).wrap('<strong/>').parent().unwrap();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wo6td7az/)**

This results in:

```
<strong>Some text </strong><span>and some more text.</span><strong> And a little more.</strong>
```

Comment: I like this way a lot, but it's dense.  For those who don't understand, this takes all text nodes that are children of the strong element (textNode type is 3), wraps all of them in strong tags, then removes the original strong tag that wrapped everything.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was trying to do. Thank you very much.
@taylorc93, if you have a faster solution, would you be able to edit your answer with it? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: I highly doubt I can get a better solution than this.  Even I learned something here, didn't realize that each node in the DOM had a type that was accessible like this.

Comment: @taylorc93 - thanks for adding the explanation. I was caught up working on the code. Appreciated.

Comment: @j08691 Thanks for the link, MDN always has the best documentation. I always figured that there was something like that for DOM elements, I just didn't realize it was openly accessible to developers

Comment: @j08691 if I understand your solution correctly, at `$("strong").contents().filter(function () {
    return (this.nodeType==3)
}).wrap('<strong/>')` the HTML should be somewhat like `<strong>Some text </strong><span>and some more text.</span></strong><strong> And a little more.</strong></strong>` and the browser is ignoring the `</strong>` tag around `span` right?

Comment: @NishanthMatha - I think you're confused by the `.wrap('<strong/>')`. That's just shorthand for `.wrap('<strong></strong>')`.

Comment: my doubt is even `<span>and some more text.</span>` isw a child node of `<strong>` right then why isn't the `span` wrapped with strong. I was expecting the output to be `<strong>Some text </strong><strong><span>and some more text.</span></strong><strong> And a little more.</strong>` thank you for you help!

Answer (score 1):

As requested, here's the method I was talking about.  I used jQuery and broke it up into more lines than necessary for simplicity, but you can condense/use built in JS functions if you prefer. Play around with it here: https://jsfiddle.net/vmge8a7j/

```
var strongElem = $("strong");
var spanElem   = $("span");

$("span").remove();

$("#parent").append(spanElem);
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the answer. I realized my question was a bit ambiguous and have clarified it. Would a similar solution to this work with the new example?

Comment: I see the difference.  Do you mind if I ask why you need it that way? Adding extra closing tags like that is verbose and unnecessary

Comment: Sorry, totally didn't read the change correctly first. Disregard my first comment, I was wrong

Comment: I would like to remove styling from parts of text but not others. I use span as an example, the stuff within the span should not be bold, whereas the stuff outside the span should be bold. How would I go about changing this method to work with the new example?

Comment: No worries, I appreciate the help and advice.

Comment: @j08691 answered it perfectly, I'd use that method.  I explained it in a comment if you don't understand it

Answer (score 0):

```
var span = $("strong span").detach();
var strong = $("strong").contents().wrap("<strong/>").end().append(span).contents().unwrap();
```

```js
var span = $("strong span").detach();
var strong = $("strong").contents().wrap("<strong/>").end().append(span).contents().unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>hello all<span>hello</span> this text has no span </strong>
```

Comment: If the span was location somewhere in the middle of the strong, with text on both sides, would this still work?

Comment: It would be like this  `<strong>stuff<span>span</span> strong</strong>`

`<strong>stuff strong</strong><span>span</span>`